# Question from Schutz's

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In q. 22 in page 141, I am asked to show that if

$$U^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha} V^{\beta} = W^{\beta},$$

then

$$U^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}V_{\beta}=W_{\beta}.$$

Here's what I have done:
$$V_{\beta}=g_{\beta \gamma} V^{\gamma},$$
so
$$U^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} (g_{\beta \gamma} V^{\gamma})=U^{\alpha}(\nabla_{\alpha} g_{\beta \gamma}) V^{\gamma} + g_{\beta \gamma} (U^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} V^{\gamma}).$$

Now, I understand that the second term is $W_{\beta}$, but how come the first term vanishes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The covariant derivative is metric compatible, so $\nabla_{\alpha} g_{\beta \gamma} = 0$. This is the condition that the inner product is preserved under parallel transport.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need metric compatibility to prove this although you can use it. There is a much simpler way with repeated use of (any) metric to lower the index.

$
U^\alpha\nabla_\alpha V^\beta=W^\beta
$

$
\Rightarrow U^\alpha g^{\beta\gamma}\nabla_\alpha V_\gamma=g^{\beta\gamma}V_\gamma
$

$
\Rightarrow U^\alpha g_{\mu\beta}g^{\beta\gamma}\nabla_\alpha V_\gamma=g_{\mu\beta}g^{\beta\gamma}V_\gamma
$

$
\Rightarrow U^\alpha\delta_\mu^\gamma\nabla_\alpha V_\gamma=\delta_\mu^\gamma V_\gamma
$

$
\Rightarrow U^\alpha\nabla_\alpha V_\mu=V_\mu
$

there are three ways to do the first step, only one uses metric compatibility. More at https://www.general-relativity.net/2019/10/symmetries-and-killing-vectors.html